# What's the difference between UINavigationController and UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I don't understand what is the difference between
`self.navigationcontroller.navigationitem` and `self.navigationitem`
i have navigation based application and in `viewDidLoad` method in `rootViewController` of navigationController I set the NavigationItem titleView to custom image by using this code

```
UIImageView* titleImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView =titleImage;
```

by the way if i try to change titleview by this way

```
UIImageView* titleImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.navigationcontroller.navigationItem.titleView =titleImage;
```

nothing was happened.
, and when navigationcontroller pushed the another view to the stack the titleview of navigationitem is cleared and reference sets to nil, and also i noticed that the references of **`self.navigationcontroller.navigationitem`** and **`self.navigationitem`** are not the same.

Comment: Please post your question in proper format so reader can get idea what you are asking and give you the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is the following: `self.navigationController.navigationItem` and `self.navigationItem`. I am ignoring the rest of the question since it is not really essential to the question.

From what I understand `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is useless since it is accessing navigation item of the navigation controller (ie your rootViewController).What you really want is `self.navigationItem`, navigation item of the view controller because that is what essentially going to show up in your view controller.

`UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` so `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is just a spillover method from subclassing. It does not do anything positive (at least in my experience).

**Edit**: Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further clarification.

Comment: in that case why the self.navigationitem in difference viewcontrollers is not the same ?

Comment: the word `self` should already tell you that you are talking about each of the viewController separately. It should not be the same since navigationItem is a property of ViewController. I never said they were the same, in fact I said they are always to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

They are Different. If you dynamically add `UINavigationController`, then you use `self.navigationController.navigationItem`.

Please better clarify your question.

Comment: This is incorrect, even if you dynamically create a `UINavigationController`, you should access the view controller's `navigationItem`